# alphanumeric zero padding in dataTables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, google-sheets

I feel like this has a "duh" answer, but

I am using the jQuery Plugin DataTables.net to display a json Google Spreadsheet. You can see it in action here: http://jsfiddle.net/ukoku/jEqu2/2/

I would like to sort the rows by the Location column, which reads in A1, B2 format, like chess. With numbers I know I'd need zero padding, but I have no idea how to add zeros to alphanumeric data, nor do I have any clue how to do it with DataTables instead of regular string.

EDIT: Sorry, I wasn't clear. The place where I thought zeros needed to be added was between the alphabetic character and the number in the Location slot. Currently, Q9 sorts as being after Q14, for example. I need it to sort first by alpha (Ax, Bx), then within that sort as numbers. Normally when I've had 1 show up as higher than 10, it's because I needed to padleft with zeros to get 001 and 010. But I'm not sure how to stick zeros between the numbers for Q009 and Q014, etc., or it that's even the proper solution.

Eventually, the goal is to customize the CSS to display rows with the same location in groups. I honestly have no idea if this is possible either, but since I can't even get the data sorted....

Comment: Where do you want to add zeroes?

Comment: Would be helpful if you could update the jsfiddle with a data source containing the types of numbers you describe for the Location column

Comment: Updated, Siharth.

Geuis: it should be loading a spreadsheet with 4 data examples.

Answer (score 2):

Is this on the right track of what you're after? http://jsfiddle.net/rMUWD/

Comment: Hooray, that does seem to be working! I see you turned them into arrays, but I'm not quite sure what you did otherwise. I'd love a short explanation if you have time. (I'm hazy with terminology.)

Comment: In the sort functions, I set 4 vars. I split the first characters of each, substr(0,1), from the rest of the string which is an int, parseInt(substr(1)). Then for the actual sort I compare char-vs-char vars first, and if they match, compare the int vars instead. Hope that explains it (I'm not a JS wiz by any means, but have some experience hacking together stuff with the datatables library).

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to do it:

```
var compare = function(a, b) {
        return a > b ? 1 : a === b ? 0 : -1;
    },
    compareAlphanumeric = function (a, b) {
        alpha = compare(a.alpha, b.alpha);
        numeric = compare(a.numeric, b.numeric);
        return (alpha === 1 | (alpha === 0 && numeric === 1)) ? 1 : (alpha === 0 && numeric === 0) ? 0 : -1;
    };
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['alphaNumeric-asc'] = function(a, b) {
    var r = /^([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+$)/,
        a = {
            "alpha": a.split(r)[1],
            "numeric": parseInt(a.split(r)[2], 10)
        },
        b = {
            "alpha": b.split(r)[1],
            "numeric": parseInt(b.split(r)[2], 10)
        };
        return compareAlphanumeric(a, b);
};
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['alphaNumeric-desc'] = function(a, b) {
    var r = /^([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+$)/,
        a = {
            "alpha": a.split(r)[1],
            "numeric": parseInt(a.split(r)[2], 10)
        },
        b = {
            "alpha": b.split(r)[1],
            "numeric": parseInt(b.split(r)[2], 10)
        };
        return compareAlphanumeric(b, a); //reverse a and b for desc
};
```

Working fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jEqu2/3/

The `compare` function is your basic comparison function. `compareAlphanumeric` returns 1, 0, or -1 based on the following truth table:

```
/*
        Alpha   Numeric     Result
        -1      -1          -1
        -1      0           -1
        -1      1           -1
        0       -1          -1
        0       0           0
        0       1           1
        1       -1          1
        1       0           1
        1       1           1
*/
```

The bulk of the actual work is done in the `oSort` functions:

```
//First declare a RegExp to split the location into an array of [letter, number] 
var r = /^([A-Za-z]+)([0-9]+$)/,
//convert the passed "a" parameter to an object containing its letter and number,
//and parse the number portion to an actual number instead of its string representation.
    a = {
        "alpha": a.split(r)[1],
        "numeric": parseInt(a.split(r)[2], 10)
    },
//do the same for b
    b = {
        "alpha": b.split(r)[1],
        "numeric": parseInt(b.split(r)[2], 10)
    };
//return the alphanumeric comparison
    return compareAlphanumeric(a, b);
```

and in the descending `oSort`, we only have to switch the order of the parameters passed to `compareAlphanumeric`.